# Three.js - PlaneGeometry from Math.Plane

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, linear-algebra, plane

I am trying to draw a least squares plane through a set of points in Three.js. I have a [plane](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Plane) defined as follows:

```
var plane = new THREE.Plane();
plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(normal, point).normalize();
```

My understanding is that I need to take that plane and use it to come up with a Geometry in order to create a mesh to add to the scene for display:

```
var dispPlane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
scene.add(dispPlane);
```

I've been trying to apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665067/three-js-how-do-you-get-a-plane-from-a-vector-and-a-constant) to get the geometry. This is what I came up with:

```
plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(dir, centroid).normalize();
planeGeometry.vertices.push(plane.normal);
planeGeometry.vertices.push(plane.orthoPoint(plane.normal));
planeGeometry.vertices.push(plane.orthoPoint(planeGeometry.vertices[1]));
planeGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));

planeGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
planeGeometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

But the plane is not displayed at all, and there are no errors to indicate where I may have gone wrong.

So my question is, how can I take my Math.Plane object and use that as a geometry for a mesh?

Comment: What does planeMaterial look like? Have you tried changing planeMaterial.side? e.g., planeMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide

Comment: var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide});

Comment: I notice you're using plane.normal as a vertex: e.g., planeGeometry.vertices.push(plane.normal); That doesn't seem valid. Any luck with using plane.coplanarPoint() instead?

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck.

Comment: Btw the 3rd vertex is colinear with the 2nd -- so the triangle-face being created is essentially a straight line. Hence why you don't see anything.

Comment: @msun even more, according to console log, all the vertices have the same value which equals to `plane.normal`, thus it's even not a straight line, it's a point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach should create a mesh visualization of the plane. I'm not sure how applicable this would be towards the least-squares fitting however.

```
 // Create plane
var dir = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
var centroid = new THREE.Vector3(0,200,0);
var plane = new THREE.Plane();
plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(dir, centroid).normalize();

// Create a basic rectangle geometry
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);

// Align the geometry to the plane
var coplanarPoint = plane.coplanarPoint();
var focalPoint = new THREE.Vector3().copy(coplanarPoint).add(plane.normal);
planeGeometry.lookAt(focalPoint);
planeGeometry.translate(coplanarPoint.x, coplanarPoint.y, coplanarPoint.z);

// Create mesh with the geometry
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
var dispPlane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
scene.add(dispPlane);
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "planeGeometry.lookAt is not a function".

Comment: It looks like THREE.Geometry.lookAt() was added in THREE r82. Are you using an older version?

Answer (score 2):

```
var material = ...;
var plane = new THREE.Plane(...);

// Align to plane
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.translate(plane.coplanarPoint());
mesh.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1), plane.normal);
```

Note that `Plane.coplanarPoint()` simply returns `-normal*constant`, so it might be a better option to use `Plane.projectPoint()` to determine a center that is "close to" an arbitrary point.